# How to generate a paper-like background with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision

I'm trying to implement a random paper-like background using OpenCV.
The attached example shows the real paper document artifacts (please ignore handwriting on it).
[image]

A simple effect of raw paper is easily possible to achieve just by applying noise

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

BG_COLOR = 209

def blank_image(width=1024, height=1024):
    img = np.full((height, width, 1), BG_COLOR, np.uint8)
    return img

def noisy(image):
    row, col, ch = image.shape
    mean = 0
    sigma = 10
    gauss = np.random.normal(mean, sigma, (row, col, ch))
    gauss = gauss.reshape(row, col, ch)
    noisy = gauss + image
    return noisy

if __name__ == '__main__':
    img = blank_image()
    cv2.imwrite('out.jpg', noisy(img))
```

But it looks too uniform without artifacts above:
[image]

And I wonder what are the best approaches of generating such random structures from the first picture.

Comment: where ppl wonder, experiments are bound to happen. Create some random coords, apply some smudge, maybe create some very light-weight "stamps" of "dirt "and apply them. connect 2 coords with a thin darker (or lighter) line for creases. Apply smudges closer to the edge (where dirty hands would turn the page). Get creative. None of this is worth a question on SO though - so voting to close as "bound to lead to discussion". Come back if your experimental code fails you. This is probably going to be better suited to some kind of "art" forum

Comment: one more tip, if you got gimp2 - it got scripted filters, my guess is one would create "paper like" textures. inspect the layers of it (or steal parts) and apply those as translucent png to your picture - maybe use the mug stain as well ;o)

Comment: The easiest solution is to take pictures of empty pages, and use those to generate your backgrounds. Either pick one of the pictures at random for each case, or separate out these artifacts and paste them at random locations.

Comment: your task ist a cimputer graphics problem.
opencv is more about computer vision

Comment: have a look at procedural noise textures and related topics.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I checked gimp and don't see filters with "paper" effect. As for stamps and dirt - is there any ideas on how to generate them? They should be ellipses (or polygons) of a darker area but without strict bounds.

Comment: > have a look at procedural noise textures and related topics. Could you please point to the related reference as a starting point?

Comment: https://lodev.org/cgtutor/randomnoise.html is the first google hit I got.

Comment: [how to create old paper with gimp](https://www.google.de/search?q=gimp+make+paper+look+old&rlz=1C1CHBF_deDE771DE771&oq=gimp+create+paper&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.4919j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) - there are default filters for cloth / canvas (hence paper-like), you can leverage those. Get creative - reserach your topic.

Comment: Stamps: well make some dark splots on a white background, use some crisscross lines, apply lots of blur, put the transarency up to alsmost invisible and stamp multiple of those additive over each other until you are statisfied. Apply other filters, mix in some brown instead of real black , iterate. Save as small translucent png, apply to your page.

Comment: Maybe have a look at G'MIC (can be a added as a Gimp plugin), it has [lots of filters](https://gmic.eu/gallery/) implemented and the source code is available. You can also test [online](https://gmicol.greyc.fr/).

Answer (score 10):

Inspired with the solution provided by BoboDarph, I created a paper-like texture. Now I need to add artifacts from the real photo above.
The code is below:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


BG_COLOR = 209
BG_SIGMA = 5
MONOCHROME = 1


def blank_image(width=1024, height=1024, background=BG_COLOR):
    """
    It creates a blank image of the given background color
    """
    img = np.full((height, width, MONOCHROME), background, np.uint8)
    return img


def add_noise(img, sigma=BG_SIGMA):
    """
    Adds noise to the existing image
    """
    width, height, ch = img.shape
    n = noise(width, height, sigma=sigma)
    img = img + n
    return img.clip(0, 255)


def noise(width, height, ratio=1, sigma=BG_SIGMA):
    """
    The function generates an image, filled with gaussian nose. If ratio parameter is specified,
    noise will be generated for a lesser image and then it will be upscaled to the original size.
    In that case noise will generate larger square patterns. To avoid multiple lines, the upscale
    uses interpolation.

    :param ratio: the size of generated noise "pixels"
    :param sigma: defines bounds of noise fluctuations
    """
    mean = 0
    assert width % ratio == 0, "Can't scale image with of size {} and ratio {}".format(width, ratio)
    assert height % ratio == 0, "Can't scale image with of size {} and ratio {}".format(height, ratio)

    h = int(height / ratio)
    w = int(width / ratio)

    result = np.random.normal(mean, sigma, (w, h, MONOCHROME))
    if ratio > 1:
        result = cv2.resize(result, dsize=(width, height), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    return result.reshape((width, height, MONOCHROME))


def texture(image, sigma=BG_SIGMA, turbulence=2):
    """
    Consequently applies noise patterns to the original image from big to small.

    sigma: defines bounds of noise fluctuations
    turbulence: defines how quickly big patterns will be replaced with the small ones. The lower
    value - the more iterations will be performed during texture generation.
    """
    result = image.astype(float)
    cols, rows, ch = image.shape
    ratio = cols
    while not ratio == 1:
        result += noise(cols, rows, ratio, sigma=sigma)
        ratio = (ratio // turbulence) or 1
    cut = np.clip(result, 0, 255)
    return cut.astype(np.uint8)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cv2.imwrite('texture.jpg', texture(blank_image(background=230), sigma=4, turbulence=4))
    cv2.imwrite('texture-and-noise.jpg', add_noise(texture(blank_image(background=230), sigma=4), sigma=10))

    cv2.imwrite('noise.jpg', add_noise(blank_image(1024, 1024), sigma=10))
```

The resulting picture:
[image]

Comment: have you added the artifacts?

Comment: @JeruLuke, not yet at the moment I think how to add an image edges + black background